# Proper Project Type for Cross-platform Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I need to develop a cross-platform app that ranges from mobile to desktop to TV. App includes a huge variety of 3D elements which are vital for application's correct display.

At first, I was going to use C++ and native compilers (utilizing directives) but I have gone that road many times, there are a lot of overlapping factors you can't unify (or find work, too much, arounds to overcome this issue), so I decided to try other alternatives.

I found Xamarin most outstanding cross-platform toolkit allowing native performance applications but I got lost in some terminology. In my application, there will be a base class called "GraphRenderer". I will override it for each platform and on each platform, I will include a different GPU library (eg. Metal for Mac, DirectX 12 for Windows, Vulkan for Android) and utilize it. If possible, I don't want to use directives, creating interfaces approach seem way more cleaner in the long run.

Is there a project type (as you can imagine Shared Library, PCL etc. left me confused)  that allows this hierarchy:

- App
- - Shared Code Files
- - - GraphRenderer.cs : Definition of GraphRenderer with Empty Functions to make it compatible for other shared code
- - Platform-Specific Code Files
- - - GraphRenderer.Windows.cs : Replaces GraphRenderer.cs when compiling App for Windows 10 platform, includes DirectX 12 headers and override functions with proper functionality

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches one is shared and another PCL
In shared approach you have to use directives as you will be using single shared file in all platforms.
In PCL approach you need to have an interface created in PCL project and implement in platform specific projects.

Comment: Does PCL allow platform-specific library inclusion?

Comment: PCL will be included in platform specific library. PCL is shared among all

Comment: Assume I have an initializer function in PCL which creates a variable with GraphRenderer class, is there a way of making initializer function use overridden GraphRenderer class on platform specific library without rewriting or passing parameter?

Comment: Your PCL will have only interface to render method from platform independent code, but final output is shown in platform specific view. The main question here would be are you trying to use xamarin classic or xamarin.forms ?

Comment: After some digging I found out that I need to use latest .NET Standard Library and create an auto-packaging tool for different platforms. At first, I thought Xamarin was handling everything automatically for platforms (in case we wrote extensions of base classes for each platform) ranging from smartwatches to smartphones to desktop to TVs but it is not that tool **yet**. There are some gaps for some platforms. It seems like creating a .NET Standard library and developing a shadow-code generator to compile to each platform seems the way to go, correct me if mistaken.